# How to start MySQL after failure?

Tags: mysql, authentication

After I reboot my server, I can no longer start mysql.

I have followed several solutions posted here:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430362/ubuntu-20-04-set-mysql-phpmyadmin-root-password)
- [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120718/cant-log-into-mysql)
- [Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419142/can-not-login-to-mysql-ubuntu-18-04)
  Did not help much... :(

I run the following commands to start the service:

```
mysql
>> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

```
sudo service mysql start
>> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
systemctl status mysql.service
>> mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-01-26 15:18:33 UTC; 47s ago
    Process: 2612 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

```
 journalctl -xe
>> Startup of the manager took 379405 microseconds.
Jan 26 14:33:24 sumentserver polkit-agent-helper-1[2223]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=0 tty= >
-- Reboot --
Jan 26 14:44:33 sumentserver systemd[1685]: Reached target Paths.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
```

The server has Ubuntu 20.4

Any tip about what can I do?

Comment: It is giving not enough info about why it failed., normally a logfile (/var/log/mysql/...) is being generated, does that not give a clue about what failed?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Did you recently upgrade?  Did your OS come with a different copy of MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem today ,the source of the issue might be different but, read carefully `/var/log/mysql/error.log` it should point to the error.

I deleted one table that I didn't need `.MYD` and `.MYI` files. It was a mistake , I should drop the table , but my server was on 100% memory usage.

What I did was reading the error on:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Keep two terminal open at the same time,
first run

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

on first terminal , then run on the second terminal

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service   ---to shut it down
sudo systemctl start mysql.service  ---to try and start up and see the reason why it is not starting.
```

For me it was:

```
2022-01-26T16:30:36.213788Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2022-01-26T16:30:36.213802Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2022-01-26T16:30:36.213830Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace 605 was not found at ./contratti/ip_log2_bak.ibd.
2022-01-26T16:30:36.213840Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore this and to permanently lose all changes to the tablespace.
2022-01-26T16:30:36.644359Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
2022-01-26T16:30:38.045091Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-01-26T16:30:38.062994Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.34-log) starting as process 2843 ...
2022-01-26T16:30:38.416074Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
```

I was able to fixing by adding on `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
innodb_force_recovery = 2
```

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

> If you are able to dump your tables with an innodb_force_recovery
> value of 3 or less, then you are relatively safe that only some data
> on corrupt individual pages is lost.

After this change I stopped and started again MySQL and it is working great.

Comment: That is a good tip. In my case it led me to: 2022-01-26T15:10:01.855905Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBS>
Configuration fixed.

Thanks a lot! This saved the day!

Comment: Is `ip_log2` one of your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Following debuging commens from @Ergest Basha, after checking the logs it looked like a configuration issue:

2022-01-26T15:10:01.855905Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBS>

Roll back to default

Comment: Please show us your `my.cnf`.

Comment: NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER was removed in MySQL 8.0 and it is no longer recognized. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011071/20860